# Auto updation of product price when its corresponding quantiy changes using jquery in a shopping cart

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to develop just like a following site[enter link description here](https://www.truffleshuffle.co.uk/store/shopping_cart.php)

Here when the user tries to purchase many items, his cart is displayed.And he can try to change the quantity of any item.When he changes the quantity of an item,the corresponding price of that item has to change automatically.It is done using jquery. I will provide my code here.

```
 foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):

$cnt++;
 ?>   <tr>

        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
       <td align="center"> // Quantity is given as dropdownlist.Each list has seperate select id that is generated dynamivally.such as qty1,qty2,etc.
       <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='qty<?php echo $cnt;?>' onChange="get_price(this.value,<?php echo $ar['Price']?>,<?php echo $cnt;?>)">
       <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
               $y="";
               if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                $y="selected";
                }
                echo "<option ";
                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";


            } ?>

       </select>
       </td>

        <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>

         <td name="price"><span id="priceDisplay<?php echo $cnt;?>"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>

        <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='price' id="pprice" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">
```

The next code is my jquery code

```
function get_price(val,price,cnt){     
var price1 =  val * price;   
document.write(('<span id="priceDisplay"+cnt></span>\n'));
```

Here I am calculating the price when the quantity changes.But my problem is that I don't know how to display the calculated price in the appropriate column. variable cnt is the row id passed from php. Please help me.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('head.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
   function get_price(val,price,cnt)
   {  

     var price1 =  val * price;
     $("#priceDisplay"+cnt).html(price1);


   </script>


  <?php
    if(empty($_SESSION['items'])){ ?>
<center><b><font color="red">There are no products in your cart!!</font>            </b></center>    
  <?php  
    }
   else

    {
     ?>

     <b><center><font color="green"> Your Shopping Cart!!</font></center> </b><br><br>
      <form name="formview" action="ajaxview.php" method="post">
        <?php $count=0; ?>


     <table align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="3px" border="1" bgcolor="lightblue">
        <tr>  
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
         <th>Remove</th>
        </tr> 
   <?php  

foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):

$cnt++;
 ?>   <tr>

        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
       <td align="center">
       <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='qty<?php echo $cnt;?>' onChange=get_price(this.value,<?php echo $ar['Price']?>,<?php echo $cnt;?>,) >
       <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
               $y="";
               if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                $y="selected";
                }
                echo "<option ";
                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";


            } ?>

       </select>
       </td>

        <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>

         <td name="price"><span id="priceDisplay<?php echo $cnt;?>"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>

        <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='price' id="pprice" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">  
       <td><input type='checkbox' name='remove' value='Remove' onCheck="$(this).closest('tr').remove();"> 


        <?php $tt[]=$ar['Total'];?>
       </tr>
       <?php
     endforeach;
       ?>

    </table>
   </form>
        <!--<table align="right">-->
      <?php foreach($tt as $t)
      {
        $count=$count+$t;
      }

     ?>  
    <br>
    <br>
      <b><center><div class="total">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Total:<span id="tot"><?php echo $count; ?></span></div></center></b>
    <b><div class="cart">Your Cart:<span class="ycart"><?php echo $x; ?></span>       </div></b>
```

Comment: I have posted my entire code.Please check it and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps,

```
  function get_price(val,price,cnt){
    var price1 =  val * price;  
    document.getElementById('priceDisplay'+cnt).innerHTML =price1;
    //$('#priceDisplay'+cnt).html(price1); //jquery     

  }
```

Using Jquery to acheive this,

```
              $(document).ready(function() {    

         $(".myclass").change(function(){
                 var identifier = $(this).attr('id');
                 var Qty = $(this).val();
                 var Price = $("#price_"+identifier).val();//price value
                 var Total =  Qty * Price;                   
                 $("#priceDisplay_"+identifier).html(Total);                 
                 GrandTotal();
               });
             GrandTotal();       

            });


         function GrandTotal(){
            var GrandTotal=0;
             $(".myclass").each(function(){
                 var identifier = $(this).attr('id');
                 var Qty = $(this).val();
                 var Price = $("#price_"+identifier).val();//price value
                 var Total =  Qty * Price;                   

                 GrandTotal += Total;
                 $("#priceDisplay_"+identifier).html(Total);    
               });

          $("#GrandTotal").html(GrandTotal);

        }

         function RemoveCart(ob){

             var IdForRemove =ob.value;

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "RemoveCart.php",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: { id: IdForRemove}
                 })
                 .done(function( data ) {
                     $("#GrandTotal").html(data.Grandtotal);                    

                     $("#"+IdForRemove).remove();

                 });

             return false;
         }


            <table>
                <?php
                  $cnt =0;
                  //  session_start();
                  //   $_SESSION['r'] = array('0'=>array('Name'=>'test 1','Price'=>'50.5','Id'=>'1', 'Quantity'=>'3'), '1'=>array('Name'=>'test 2','Price'=>'100','Id'=>'2', 'Quantity'=>'4'), '2'=>array('Name'=>'test 3','Price'=>'150','Id'=>'3', 'Quantity'=>'5'));
                 $CartR = $_SESSION['r'];


               foreach($CartR as $key=>$ar):

               $Identifier = 'qty_'.$cnt;
            ?>  
                <tr id="<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>">

                     <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
                     <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
                     <td align="center"> // Quantity is given as dropdownlist.Each list has seperate select id that is generated dynamivally.such as qty1,qty2,etc.
                            <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='<?php echo $Identifier;?>' >
                            <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
                                    $y="";
                                    if( $i==$ar['Quantity']){
                                        $y='selected="selected"';
                                     }
                                     echo "<option value='".$i."' $y> $i</option>\n";


                                 } ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>

                         <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>

                         <td name="price"><span id="priceDisplay_<?php echo $Identifier;?>"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>

                        <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid_<?php echo $Identifier;?>" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='price' id="price_<?php echo $Identifier;?>" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">  

                        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="RemoveCart(this)" value="<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>"> Remove
             </tr>

              <?php  $cnt++;  endforeach;  ?> 
     </table>

       Grand Total: <div id="GrandTotal"></div>
```

Create new file "RemoveCart.php"  and below lines into that page,

```
      <?php session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['id'])){

                $toBeRemove =$_POST['id'];
                $CartR =$_SESSION['r'];

                    foreach($CartR as $key=>$Cart){                     

                        if($Cart['Id']==$toBeRemove){                   

                            unset($_SESSION['r'][$key]);

                        }
                    }
                    $CartR = $_SESSION['r'];
                    $Grandtotal =0;
                    foreach($CartR as $key=>$Cart){

                        $Grandtotal += $Cart['Quantity'] * $Cart['Price'];
                    }


                    echo json_encode(array('Grandtotal'=> "$Grandtotal"));
            }


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
document.write(('<span id="priceDisplay"+cnt></span>\n'));
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById("priceDisplay"+cnt).innerHTML=price1;
```

Using Jquery:

```
$("#priceDisplay"+cnt).html(price1);
```

Comment: Thank you Joke, but I need it purely in jquery.the above of you I have tried and I got the answer.But I need to do it completely in jquery.Please help me.

Comment: Check my updated answer.If you find it relevant and useful then accept the answer.:)

Comment: No.Joke,its not working!! I have been trying this for 2 days. But its not working! I don't know where I have went wrong.Please help me...

Comment: You included jquery library ryte?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>  I included this.Is there anything more to include Joke?

Comment: Post your entire code..and that's an old library though he doesn't make a difference..

Comment: You have not initialized `$cnt` variable instead you are directly increementing it. Do something like `$cnt=1;`

Answer (score 0):

You want it in jquery. Use

```
$("#id").html("hello World");
```

Change the id to the id you want to use. And the text as well

Comment: Yeah I know that the syntax is this.But I am not able find the unique id for each row.In my code 'cnt' is my row id.I know that I have to use cnt along with my span id.But I don't know the exact syntax.Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using for loop, with incriminating the variable part? I mean form the id with conacating the "qty" and the variable. It will set all the prices but you always have the  original price , so you can calculate for all of them. ()